# PHP Warning is still on screen despite error_reporting(E_ALL) & usage of error_log type 3

Tags: php, error-handling, error-logging, error-log

My PHP version is 5.5.7.

I set `error_reporting(E_ALL);`

then I intentionally wrote my database password wrong.

when I was using `die()` before usage of `error_log()`, my screen displays 2 messages: A warning and error:

`Warning: mysqli::mysqli(): (42000/1044): Access denied for user 'user'@'%' to database 'database' in /folder/folder/folder/www/folder/file.php on line 2`

`Connect Error (1044) Access denied for user 'user'@'%' to database 'database'`

And after deleting `die()` codes and applying the code below, I expected all logs on the custom log file. However; while the Log file has the message I created, I still got the warning on screen with sensitive info.

```
$DBconn = new mysqli($DBhost, $DBuser, $DBpass, $DBname, $DBport);

if ($DBconn->connect_error) 
{           
    error_log("Connect Error! ".$DBconn->connect_errno.' '.$DBconn->connect_error."\n\r", 3, "/home/www/host/PHP_errors.log");
}
```

**question:**

what am I doing wrong? how can I achieve all kind of errors are printed into log file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, mysqli throws PHP warnings for errors. This is not ideal, especially in your situation where you want to see errors but do not want the sensitive information about your database displayed on the screen.

What I recommend is that you change the report mode of mysqli to throw Exceptions instead - this way you can catch them and then handle and log. My example below shows how you might do that:

```
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);

try {

    $DBconn = new mysqli($DBhost, $DBuser, $DBpass, $DBname, $DBport);

} catch (Exception $e) {

    error_log(
        "Connect Error! ".$e->getMessage()."\n",
        3,
        "/home/www/host/PHP_errors.log"
    );

}
```

If you're not a fan of exceptions - then you can disable reporting of PHP warnings by changing your `error_reporting` declaration to exclude them like this:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_WARNING);
```

But this will disable reporting of **all** warnings - not just those from mysqli.

Comment: I used 1st proposal (with exception). It worked. Now, there exist no  sensitive data on screen. (Warning on screen has gone) Error is logged to my log file. thanks. regards.

Answer (score 0):

The display of errors on screen is controlled by the [`display_errors`](http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-errors) directive. Setting the other two is independent of that.